# Converting single vector of regression coefficients to linear predictor in stata

Tags: vector, stata

I have obtained a vector of regression coefficients from a lasso regression using the plogit ado in Stata.
It is a 1 x 60 vector of regression coefficients with column names present.
I need obtain the linear predictor from this by multiplying each coefficient by the variable value for each subject.

Is it possible to extract the column names into a vector which by multiplying by the coefficient vectors will provide the  linear predictor for each subject

Comment: Can't you use `predict`?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty obscure user-written command, and it would have been helpful for you to clarify [its murky origins](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucakgam/stata.html). You might have gotten an answer sooner!

Though it does not say so, `plogit` does allow you to follow it up with `predict` to get the index function, and getting the predicted probabilities is just a matter of wrapping the `invlogit()` function around that. I also did it by hand just for fun.

```
sysuse auto, clear
plogit foreign weight mpg, lasso lambda(2)

/* A. With Predict */
predict double phat, xb
replace phat = invlogit(phat)

/* B. By Hand */
/* (1) get a list of coefficients */
local coefs: colnames e(b) 

/* (2) Build the index function expression */
foreach x of local coefs {
    if "`x'" !=  "_cons" {
        local index "`index' `=_b[`x']'*`x' +"
    }
    else {
        local index "`index' `=_b[`x']'"
    }
}

/* (3) predict phat */
gen double phat2 = invlogit(`index')
```